# Is it possible to make google translate (full site translate with chrome) not translate numbers?

Tags: google-chrome, numbers, translation, translate

Google translate seem to sometime translate numbers from sites in chinese/japanese/korean, like if the original source says 25, it will translate it to "twenty five". Is it possible to blacklist numbers from google translate site translation in chrome?